# Passing Values from XML to Web Service Using SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I've been having trouble accomplishing the following task and was looking for input from the community on how I might go about solving it; if this is the wrong place to post this, please let me know and I will move it.

Using a SSIS package I am trying to:

1. Read values from an XML document.
2. Pass those values to a web service.
3. Record the return value in a new XML document (or a flat-file for simplicity sake).

---

For reference, let's take a simple example. I want to pass a series of currency types to this web service:

http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx

So far I have:

Added HTTP Connection Manager - Configured to access the WSDL file at http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl

Created a Web Service Task using the HTTP Connection, made and referenced the WSDL file.

The input fields can be selected manually, for example, CAD to USD.

The output can be easily saved to a specified output.

I have two main problems; the first would be passing the columns from the XML source to the web service and the second is I'm not sure how to handle the datatypes of the web service. In the example web service, the datatype for the currency is "Currency" but that is not a defined datatype within BIDS.

Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

emphasized textcheck out this link which passes data from a flat file source to a web service.

http://www.vsteamsystemcentral.com/cs/blogs/applied_team_system/archive/2007/01/10/247.aspx